# How do I use get_header() in a plugin in wordpress to load a header file within the plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to use get_header('tw'); in a page template in my wordpress plugin. The header-tw.php file is located in the plugin folder root but when I call get_header('tw') it is not loading that file and is instead defaulting to get_header() in main theme.

Comment: Your page template is probably not loading. If you remove the call completely is the header gone completely? Are you sure the template is being loaded?

Comment: thanks, but I checked that.  It was writing out the page template ok,  but not resolving to call the header file in the plugin and instead reverting to the header file in the theme.